# Attempt to read property "name" on null in laravel relations

Tags: foreign-keys, laravel-blade, relationship, laravel-relations, laravel-models

i made one-to-many relation in laravel with category and product, but the problem is that the relation is ok to categroy side but on the product side when i fetch data then they say me "Attempt to read property "name" on null" [[this is category model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv0pM.jpg)][this is product blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnDIc.jpg)]

[this is product model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCntT.jpg)

[this is product controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxFmy.jpg)
i am trying to fetch the product with related category name

Answer (score 0):

setting up a basic one-to-many relationship between **Category** and **Product** models in Laravel

Imagin you have a **Category** model with the following product relationship

```
// Category.php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

And a Product model with the following category relationship

```
// Product.php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Now, in the controller, when fetching products with their related category name, you can use eager loading

```php
// ProductController.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::with('category')->get();
        return view('products.index', compact('products'));
    }
}
```

In your blade view **'products/index.blade.php'** , you can loop through the products and access the related category name

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <p>{{ $product->name }} - {{ $product->category->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Make sure your database tables are set up with the **foreign key** constraints correctly. The products table should have a **category_id** column that references the id column in the categories table